# Flutter argument persistence between pushed routes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

so I'm at a cross roads on the next app I'm doing. I have four routes, each of which add a new argument that will all be tied together at a final screen.

So let's say there's four routes and I called these three functions (starting at route 1)

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'route2', arguments: <String, String>{'foo': 'bar'});
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'route3', arguments: <String, String>{'fizz': 'buzz'});
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'route4', arguments: <String, String>{'mumbo': 'jumbo'});
```

Would I have access to all of the arguments in the final route? so could I access 'foot','fizz', and 'mumbo'

Comment: i think you will need to add them to the arguments every time. you might want to consider app state management https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you have to extract the arguments of the route in the route's widget by using the context of the widget, like

```dart
final args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

So, the arguments of the route outside of the one you defined the arguments for, won't have access to those arguments. For example, `route3` won't be able to use the argument `foo` for that is defined for `route1`.

To answer your question, you won't have access to all of these arguments in the final route, since these arguments are not defined for that final route. You probably might want to use state management for that.